# parsing xml asynctask and writing in listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

i want to parse my xml in asynctask because it won´t work without asynctask on android 4.0 +.The problem is that i cant write my strings in listview on my asynctask.

Here is my xml parsing activity:

```
package de.heron.cloudbox;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity{

    String dwnload_file_path = "http://h.t-softec.de/heron.website.app/android/everhomeapp.xml";
    String dest_file_path = "http://h.t-softec.de/heron.website.app/android/everhomeapp.xml";
    Button b1;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    ///storage/emulated/0/everhomeapp.xml
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://h.t-softec.de/heron.website.app/android/everhomeapp.xml";
//file:///storage/emulated/0/everhomeapp.xml
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "device"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "deviceid";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "devicename";
    static final String KEY_actionid = "actions";
    static final String KEY_actionid2 = "actions2";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "devicetype";
    static final String KEY_texton = "texton";
    static final String KEY_textoff = "textoff";
    ArrayList<String> mImageLink;
    String[] actions = new String[] {
            "Alle Räume",
            "Wohnzimmer",
            "Küche",
            "Gäste-Wc"
        };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.leftright, R.anim.rightleft );
        setTitle("Geräte");
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

try{
        XMLParserLocal parser = new XMLParserLocal();
          File file = new File("/sdcard/everhomeapp.xml");
          InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_actionid, parser.getValue(e, KEY_actionid));
            map.put(KEY_actionid2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_actionid2));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_texton, parser.getValue(e, KEY_texton));
            map.put(KEY_textoff, parser.getValue(e, KEY_textoff));
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}
        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_ID, KEY_actionid, KEY_texton, KEY_textoff}, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost, R.id.deviceid,R.id.on,R.id.off });

        setListAdapter(adapter2);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String cost2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String deviceid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceid)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();
                String on = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.on)).getText().toString();
                String off = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.off)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_actionid, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_actionid2, cost2);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ID, deviceid);
                in.putExtra(KEY_texton, on);
                in.putExtra(KEY_textoff, off);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        try {
        URL url = new URL("http://h.t-softec.de/heron.website.app/android/everhomeapp.xml");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"everhomeapp.xml");
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        int downloadedSize = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
        }
        parseFile();
        fileOutput.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        parseFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        parseFile();
}
    }

    public void parseFile(){


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
try{
        XMLParserLocal parser = new XMLParserLocal();
          File file = new File("/sdcard/everhomeapp.xml");
          InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_actionid, parser.getValue(e, KEY_actionid));
            map.put(KEY_actionid2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_actionid2));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_texton, parser.getValue(e, KEY_texton));
            map.put(KEY_textoff, parser.getValue(e, KEY_textoff));

            menuItems.add(map);
        }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_ID, KEY_actionid, KEY_texton, KEY_textoff}, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost, R.id.deviceid,R.id.on,R.id.off });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String deviceid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceid)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();
                String on = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.on)).getText().toString();
                String off = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.off)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_actionid, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ID, deviceid);
                in.putExtra(KEY_texton, on);
                in.putExtra(KEY_textoff, off);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

    }
    public void parsexmllocal(){

         mImageLink = new ArrayList<String>();

         try{

         File file = new File("mnt/sdcard/kursywalut.xml");
         InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

         NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");

         for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

             Node node = nodeList.item(i);

             Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

             mImageLink.add(fstElmnt.getAttribute("link"));
         }
         } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }
    }
      public void downloadFile(String url, String dest_file_path) {
          try {
              File dest_file = new File(dest_file_path);
              URL u = new URL(url);
              URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
              int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
              DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
              byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
              stream.readFully(buffer);
              stream.close();
              DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file));
              fos.write(buffer);
              fos.flush();
              fos.close();
              hideProgressIndicator();

          } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
              hideProgressIndicator();
              return; 
          } catch (IOException e) {
              hideProgressIndicator();
              return; 
          }
    }

    void hideProgressIndicator(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main,  menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    public void clicksound(View view){

          MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clicksound);  
          mp.start();

        }
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.refresh:  
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://h.t-softec.de/heron.website.app/android/everhomeapp.xml");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"everhomeapp.xml");
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                int downloadedSize = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Geräteliste erfolgreich aktualisiert!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fileOutput.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
            Handler handler4 = new Handler();
            handler4.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                 @Override
                 public void run()
                 {
            parseFile();
                 }
            }, 100);

            break;
        case R.id.change:   
              Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);
            break;
        case android.R.id.home: 
            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, AndroidXMLParsingActivity2.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is my singlemenuitemactivity:

```
package de.heron.cloudbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {
    EditText txtCode;
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_actionid = "cost";
    static final String KEY_actionid2 = "cost2";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    static final String KEY_ID = "deviceid";
    static final String KEY_texton = "texton";
    static final String KEY_textoff = "textoff";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get XML values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
        String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_actionid);
        String cost2 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_actionid2);
        String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
        String deviceid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ID);
        String on = in.getStringExtra(KEY_texton);
        String off = in.getStringExtra(KEY_textoff);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
        TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);
        TextView lblid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_label);
       // TextView lblon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.on);
       // TextView lbloff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.off);
        Button lblon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.on);
        lblon.getText().toString();
        lblon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", 0);
                    txtCode.setText(settings.getString("Code", "").toString());
                    String[] url={"http://everhome.de/api/applive/", (settings.getString("Code", "")), "/" + KEY_ID,"/" + KEY_actionid};
                    new onoff(SingleMenuItemActivity.this).execute(url);
                }});
        Button lbloff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.off);
        lbloff.getText().toString();
        lbloff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String[] url={"http://everhome.de/api/applive/", "8ef43502ad3dc04f87b4a48b993878c0","/" + KEY_ID,"/" + KEY_actionid2};
                    new onoff(SingleMenuItemActivity.this).execute(url);
                }
                });
        lblName.setText(name);
        lblCost.setText(cost);
        lblCost.setText(cost2);
        lblDesc.setText(description);
        lblid.setText(deviceid);
        lblon.setText(on);
        lbloff.setText(off);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setTitle("Geräte");

        Button devices = (Button) findViewById(R.id.devices);
        devices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, AndroidXMLParsingActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
        });
        Button scenes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scenes);
        scenes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, AndroidXMLParsingActivity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main,  menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.refresh:  

            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

i hope anybody can help me to resolve my problem.
Update:

thats was the test with asynctask:

```
class xmlparse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "device"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "deviceid";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "devicename";
    static final String KEY_actionid = "actions";
    static final String KEY_actionid2 = "actions2";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "devicetype";
    static final String KEY_texton = "texton";
    static final String KEY_textoff = "textoff";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /*
                    make connection & download XML here, 
                    use your XML parser class object to parse the xml from here

                    create ArrayList & etc. from here...

                */
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //
        //File xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        //Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
try{
        XMLParserLocal parser = new XMLParserLocal();
          File file = new File("/sdcard/everhomeapp.xml");
          InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_actionid, parser.getValue(e, KEY_actionid));
            map.put(KEY_actionid2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_actionid2));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_texton, parser.getValue(e, KEY_texton));
            map.put(KEY_textoff, parser.getValue(e, KEY_textoff));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // postexecute logic
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // pre execute logic
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

but the problem is that i want to put the strings(menu items ) in listview with the listadapter:

```
ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_ID, KEY_actionid, KEY_texton, KEY_textoff}, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost, R.id.deviceid,R.id.on,R.id.off });

            setListAdapter(adapter2);

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                    String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                    String cost2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                    String deviceid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceid)).getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();
                    String on = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.on)).getText().toString();
                    String off = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.off)).getText().toString();
```

and i dont know how i can make this when the parser runs in asynctask.
that make the parser to put the menuitems to the listadapter:

```
menuItems.add(map);
```

Comment: That is a whole lot of code. Also, I don't even see an `AsyncTask`. Furthermore, "The problem is that i cant write my strings in listview on my asynctask.", is not very descriptive. Please try to be more clear about your problem and post only the code you think is relevant. We will kindly ask for more if we think it is needed.

Comment: Where's your `AsyncTask`? Did you code any? I'm confused...

Comment: You can write your values from asynctask from onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute.  They run on the UI thread.

Comment: now i have add the next parts of the code with better descripton of the problem

Comment: i have found a nice example for parsing with async task on:

http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.de/2013/04/xml-pull-parser-example-in-android.html

i build now my app new with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference your adapter through a `WeakReference` when initializing your `Asynctask`.

Parametrize the `AsyncTask` to return whatever you need to return, e.g. a `List<String>`. The connection and data pulling happens in `doInBackground`.

In `onPostExecute`, check your `WeakReference.get` is not `null` and populate the adapter.